# How update database with doctrine in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I make an Entity with Entity generator, but now when I try command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

It throw following:

```
No Metadata Classes to process.
```

So, what I make wrong?

PS. I am also try write it self and use following command:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/DataPage
```

And I saw this error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping] \MappingException]  Class "AppBundle\Entity\DataPage" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

So there is code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* DataPage
*/
class DataPage
{
  /**
   * @var integer
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $sisalto;

  /**
   * @var string
   */
  private $nimi;

}
```

**EDIT**
So, I try make this for exampe code from [there](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)
And I saw that same error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping \MappingException]                                      
Class "AppBundle\Entity\Product" is not a valid entity or mapped superclass.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* DataPage
*/
class DataPage
[...]
```

should be

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="data_page")
 */
 [...]
```

This is only the first step, than you have to annotate every single field of the entity that you want to appear onto db.
Please take a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps anyone else, but I was getting the following error for the symfony Doctrine Product example code:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
Class "AppBundle\Entity\Product" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Then I took a second look at my comments section, and it was a missing asterisk like the following code sample [The below is WRONG]:

```
/*
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
```

Notice on line 1 there should be an extra '*' at the very end. I definitely did not think this would matter at all, but apparently it does.  Also don't use tabs in front of your annotations. The Doctrine group just fixed that bug too.